# sending mail to multiple email address in codeigniter php not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, phpmailer, codeigniter-3

i am trying to send mails to emails selected using checkbox in codeigniter website using phpmailer,

```
<input class="acb" type="checkbox"  name="email[]" value="<?= $val->email?>"  />
```

PHP

```
$this->load->library('phpmailer_lib');
$mail = $this->phpmailer_lib->load();
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host     = '';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = '';
$mail->Password = '';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Port     = 465;
$mail->setFrom('admin@', 'Test');
$mail->addReplyTo('admin@', 'Test');
$mail->addAddress(implode(', ', $this->input->post('email')));
$mail->Subject = 'Important';
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mailContent = $this->input->post('content');
$mail->Body = $mailContent;
$mail->send();
```

However this does not work; it gives me error.

Can anyone please tell me how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @user3783243 i get internal server error

Comment: "*It doesn't work*" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Please update your question with some code example, describe if there are any errors! Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Vickel it works fine if i add single email address, but with multiple email address its not working

Comment: If you're getting an internal server error then the actual error will be recorded in the server error log. Look there to find out what's happened.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular there is no error in server logs,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually PHPMailer code you're using, and PHPMailer's `addAddress` does not accept multiple email addresses.

http://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer-PHPMailer-PHPMailer.html#method_addAddress

You will need to loop through the list and add each individually if you want to use that method.

There is no PHP-generated error because passing extra parameters to a method  does not generate any kind of error in PHP; they are passed into the method via the `$argv` array but do not have unique variable names because you do not have parameter placeholders defined for them.

EDIT

What I just said is still true but looking at it again I see now you're only passing in a single argument, the resulting string from `implode` so it doesn't apply to this specifically.